# How to get next number in sequence in R

Tags: r, math, data-manipulation

I need to automate the process of getting the next number(s) in the given sequence.

Can we make a function which takes two inputs

1. a vector of numbers(3,7,13,21 e.g.)
2. how many next numbers

   ```
   seqNext <- function(sequ, next) {
   ..
   }

   seqNext( c(3,7,13,21), 3) 
   # 31 43 57
   seqNext( c(37,26,17,10), 1)
   # 5
   ```

Comment: How did you get 31 from the vector

Comment: I gather it's because `c(3,7,13,21)` is increasing by 4, 6, 8 so the next three would be 10, 12, 14

Comment: @RichardScriven Looks like that is the case.  So, the `by` in `seq` would be `next-1`

Comment: @RichardScriven I am right now busy with some work.  I was thinking about the getting the first number from `diff` output, then use the `seq` based on the `diff(diff`

Comment: Anyone built an R emulator for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine

Comment: @spacedman - I started puttting something together but my lounge room is full of gears and crankshafts now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the power of maths!

```
x1 <- c(3,7,13,21)
dat <- data.frame(x=seq_along(x1), y=x1)

predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data=dat), newdata=list(x=5:15))
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11 
# 31  43  57  73  91 111 133 157 183 211 241
```

When dealing with successive differences that change their sign, the pattern of output values ends up switching from decreasing to increasing:

```
x2 <- c(37,26,17,10)

dat <- data.frame(x=seq_along(x2), y=x2)
predict(lm(y ~ poly(x,2), data=dat), newdata=list(x=1:10))

# 1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10 
#37     26     17     10      5      2      1      2      5     10
   -(11)   -(9)   -(7)    -(5)   -(3)   -(1)  -(-1)  -(-3) -(-5)
        -2     -2      -2     -2     -2    -2     -2     -2
```

As a function:

```
seqNext <- function(x,n) {
  L <- length(x)
  dat <- data.frame(x=seq_along(x), y=x)
  unname(
    predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data=dat), newdata=list(x=seq(L+1,L+n)))
  )
}

seqNext(x1,5)
#[1] 31 43 57 73 91
seqNext(x2,5)
#[1] 5 2 1 2 5
```

---

This is also easily extensible to circumstances where the pattern might be `n` orders deep, e.g.:

```
x3 <- c(100, 75, 45, 5, -50)
diff(x3)
#[1] -25 -30 -40 -55
diff(diff(x3))
#[1]  -5 -10 -15
diff(diff(diff(x3)))
#[1] -5 -5

seqNext <- function(x,n,degree=2) {
  L <- length(x)
  dat <- data.frame(x=seq_along(x), y=x)
  unname(
    predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, degree), data=dat), newdata=list(x=seq(L+1,L+n)))
  )
}

seqNext(x3,n=5,deg=3)
#[1] -125 -225 -355 -520 -725
```

Comment: To be more precise, in our answers patterns can be different from Richard's not when sequences cross zero but when successive differences change their sign, i.e. when they are decreasing in absolute terms in `x`.

Comment: @RichardScriven - nothing too controversial. The decreasing pattern will continue until the slope reverses `seqNext(c(10,2,-4), 5)` as per the 2nd-order polynomial curve (which is U shaped), e.g.: `x <- seq(-4,4,0.5); plot(x,poly(x,2)[,2],type="l")`

Comment: I would say that the extension to `n` orders should be obvious.  It's what makes this a great answer.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - thanks. For a dullard like me, nothing is obvious when it comes to these sorts of calculations! The edit is mainly so I can come back and reference this post myself!

Answer (score 2):

```
seqNext <- function(x, n) {
  k <- length(x);  d <- diff(x[(k - 2):k])
  x[k] + 1:n * d[2] + cumsum(1:n) * diff(d[1:2])
}

seqNext(c(3,7,13,21),3) 
# [1] 31 43 57
seqNext(c(37,26,17,10),1)
# [1] 5
seqNext(c(137,126,117,110),10)
# [1] 105 102 101 102 105 110 117 126 137 150
seqNext(c(105,110,113,114),5)
# [1] 113 110 105  98  89
```